# callback function not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I've created a script that places a marker on a map based on the area you click your mouse over. Once that marker is placed, when your mouse hovers over the marker, an infobox should appear with the address of where the marker is placed. However, the infobox isn't showing up because when I call "info_text", it returns undefined. I realized that I needed to add in a callback function but I don't think I'm implementing it correctly. Could anyone help me fix my code? Thanks

My code:

```
var geocoder;

function initialize() 
{

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var event = google.maps.event.addListener;

  // intializing and creating the map.
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      mapOptions);

   event(map,'click',function(e){
    var marker = placeMarker_and_attachMessage(e.latLng,map,count);
    count = count + 1;
  });

} // end of initalize.

function placeMarker_and_attachMessage(position,map) 
{
    var event = google.maps.event.addListener;
    var message = ['This', 'is', 'the', 'secret', 'message'];

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map
    }); 

    var pos = info_text(position);
    alert('pos is: ' + pos);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'hello'
        });

    event(marker,'mouseover',function(){
        infowindow.open(map,this);
    });

    event(marker,'mouseout',function(){
        infowindow.close();
    });

} // end of function.

function info_text(position)
{
    var lat = parseFloat(position.lat());
    var lng = parseFloat(position.lng());
    alert('lat,lng is: ' + (lat,lng));
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    alert('just before geocode');
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) 
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            alert('in info_text If statement');
            if(results[1])
            {
                alert('in inner if statement');
                var finalResult = myCallback(results[1].formatted_address);
                 return finalResult;
            }
            else
            {
                alert('no results found');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert('could not pinpoint location');
        }

    });
}

function myCallback(loc)
{
    alert('i have a location!');
    return loc;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Hi there. You've got a slight misunderstanding of how to use callbacks in asynchronous code. May I recommend some [further reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))? The upshot is you cannot return a value from a callback in the manner you are attempting.

Comment: @Jivings: Thanks for the reply. What is the best way to return the address if my way will not work?

Comment: You need to perform the action you want in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `info_text` doesn't `return` anything, so this line:

```
var pos = info_text(position);
```

is where `pos` is undefined.

You need to include:

```
return something;
```

at some point in your function (like you have done further down).

**Added**
Your function `myCallback` returns a value, but where it is used:

```
myCallback(results[1].formatted_address);
```

it doesn't store the return-value anywhere - it is just discarded.

Comment: I set myCallback(...) to a variable and then returned it within the inner if statement. so although the "undefined" pos doesn't appear, when I hover over the marker, no info box appears... Any suggestions why that is since content --> 'hello'?

Comment: You haven't set `myCallback()` to a variable in your posted-code, so I'm a little lost.

Comment: I assume that `geocoder.geocode` is an AJAX call, so this answer wont fix the users problem.

Comment: `return finalResult;` won't work. As Jivings advised, you need to understand how Ajax and callbacks work. I was just explaining some basic errors in your code, about return values.